# How to filter data in MDX for the last year

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to write an `MDX` expression which will return total invoiced for the last year (i.e. between today and 365 days back). I currently have:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY 
      { [Measures].[Invoiced] } 
    ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
    ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
          [Date Invoiced].[Day].&[2013-10-01T00:00:00] 
          : [Date Invoiced].[Day].&[2014-10-01T00:00:00] 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
      FROM [Sales]
    )
```

I would like to replace `2014-10-01T00:00:00` with something like `Now()`, and `2013-10-01T00:00:00` with something like `(Now()-365))`, but have been unable to find the correct syntax.

The `MDX` is to be used in `PowerPivot` in `Excel 2010` which does not support parameters exposed to `VBA`, so I will not be able to substitute the dates programmatically.

Comment: you could create a custom set in Excel ? Ive not used PP so unsure if a custom set helps - once the custom set is created can you add it to the pivot's background ?

Comment: is the PP getting its data from a tabular model?

Comment: @whytheq - The PowerPivot gets its invoicing data from an SQL Server Analysis Server cube via an MDX query, not from a tabular model. I'm not sure what you mean by a "custom set in Excel".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lag function on mdx, this function returns the value of a member n positions before the supplied member within a dimension.

Here is the reference for this function:
http://mdxpert.com/Functions/MDXFunction.aspx?f=37

Here is how I use the lag for get the previous value from a dimension, in this case I got the value of the previous year.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Previous] as ([Data].CurrentMember.lag(12), [Measures].[Example])
```

Comment: The lag function can certainly be a part of a solution to this problem, but the main question remains - how to select all members in the sliding time interval between today and  (today - 12 months). This example shows how to compare a value with the same value 12 periods earlier, which is not what I am trying to do. Could you refine the example to show how to replace the hard-coded dates in the original question?